Ubuntu and active directory / group policies - login scripts possible?
In my own home LAN I have setup a windows server with active directory. I have a bunch of computers, either running ubuntu or running dual boot ubuntu and windows.
For the windows PCs, I have some GPOs that setup some things for ease of use (like drive mappings e.g.).
The ubuntu computers also joined the domain, which works nicely. Anybody can login any computer using its active directory user. The only thing I need to do, is to map network drives manually. Not a big deal, but I wonder if this is still necessary these days.
So my question, is there further integration possible yet for linux/ubuntu with active directory? E.g. is there something already existing which would mount the SysVol network share and run some scripts, somewhat similar to how windows computers interact with the domain controller?
